# Is the following condition enough for $a_n$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $a_n$ be a bounded sequence.

Does that mean that for each $N$ (Real Number) there is $\epsilon>0$ S.T for each $n,m>N$ (Natural Numbers)$|a_n-a_m|<\epsilon$

Comment: @Leo163 how that contradicts the written above? actually it proves what I wrote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going strictly by the words you have used the answer is YES. There exists $M$ such that $|a_n| <M$ for all $n$. Take $\epsilon =2M$ and your inequality holds.

The converse is also true.

Comment: may you show to to prove it formally?

Comment: $|a_n-a_m|\leq |a_n|+|a_m| <M+M=2M$. @ArielCohen

Answer (score 0):

Well yes. You know that there exists such $M$ for which $|a_{n}|<M$. Therefore, by choosing $\varepsilon=2M$ you get: $|a_{n}-a_{m}|<|a_{n}|+|a_{m}|<M+M=2M=\varepsilon$, where first inequality is derived from the triangle inequality.